# Raphael js: animating path with it's drop shadow

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm not sure how to fade in and out a path and the drop shadow I've created for it:

```
 var p = "M10,10L810,10L810,190L10,190L10,10";
  var s = "M16,16L816,16L816,196L16,196L16,16";
var paper = Raphael(100, 100, 830, 210);
var shadow = paper.path(s);
shadow.attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#999999", opacity:0.1});
shadow.blur(4);


var c = paper.path(p);
c.attr({fill:"#ffffff", stroke:"none"});
```

Do I have to manually animate c and shadow at the same time? Is there a way I can just tell this particular paper to fade everything inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your path and your shadow in a set. apply your animation to the set and it'll affect both.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/Y396M/) a really terrible example where I move both at once.

Comment: Thanks. But since safari doesnt support svg filters I may have to go the html5 canvas route.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe animating the drop shadow path to match the specification of the other path?
http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?q=fadingdropshadow

Answer (score 0):

the amadan answer is incorrect. please discard it.
If you put elements in a set, the glow will be part of the set but set is logical only.
it means that if you animate the set, your shadow animation will look wierd.

use set only to refer to logical zoning for events for instance.
best is to animate the shadows in // of the other objects.